# Gentzen's consistency proof and model of $PA+\neg Con(PA)$

Tags: logic, model-theory

Gentzen's consistency proof demonstrates that $PA$ is consistent. Does it also demonstrate there exists no model of $PA + \neg Con(PA)$? Naturally, this initially seems to be so, but if PA is consistent then there should be a model of $PA + \neg Con(PA)$. But some texts write that Gentzen's consistency proof demonstrates $Con(PA)$, which adds confusion. $Con(PA)$ is a sentence in a theory, so it is not clear if Gentzen's consistency proof actually demonstrates it. In other words, even if Gentzen's consistency proof demonstrates consistency of $PA$, $\neg Con(PA)$ being satisfied still seems possibility.

Comment: I recall consistency of PA is equivalent to well foundedness of a certain ordinal number or some such. The first sentence ought to read ' Gentzen's proof demonstrates PA is consistent iff ...'

Comment: [Gentzen's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen%27s_consistency_proof) "shows that the Peano axioms of first-order arithmetic do not contain a contradiction (i.e. are "consistent")". But it is not $\mathsf {PA} \vdash \text {Con}(\mathsf {PA})$. The proof of the consistency of $\mathsf {PA}$ is done in a meta-theory that is different from  $\mathsf {PA}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Didn't Gödel have something to say about that? PA encodes basic arithmetic, therefore cannot demonstrate its own consistency, roughly speaking.

Comment: @AlvinLepik - exactly. Gödel's Incompleteness Th is the reason way Gentzen's proof is done in a different meta-theory with respect to $\mathsf {PA}$.

Answer (score 4):

Gentzen's proof establishes Con(PA) from assumptions that are not provable in PA.  In particular, Gentzen's proof uses transfinite induction up to the ordinal $\epsilon_0$ (see [$\epsilon$ numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_numbers_(mathematics)) on Wikipedia).  This amount of transfinite induction is not provable in PA. The ordinal $\epsilon_0$ is the "proof theoretic ordinal" of PA - Gentzen's proof led to a general program of [ordinal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_analysis) to try to classify the strength of theories by their proof theoretic ordinals.

As you said, none of this contradicts the existence of models of PA + $\lnot \text{Con}(\text{PA})$. The incompleteness theorem shows that PA does not prove Con(PA), so any sufficiently strong metatheory (like ZF) will be able to construct models of  PA + $\lnot \text{Con}(\text{PA})$.

Comment: It should perhaps be added that talking about models is usually done in metatheory which lets you actually have models as objects (e.g. set theory), whereas PRA+Induction hypothesis is not normally where you'd expect to be talking about models per se.

Comment: It's true - "sufficiently strong" here has to include talking about models in some way.